# How to center react-draggable element on start? (modal, div)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to center react-draggable element on start?
I have a modal that is wrapped by react-draggable a component. I would like to after the modal is open, center his position in a browser. 
I try pass to a defaultPosition a percentage value but I'm not able to pass percentage `defaultPostion={{ x:  50%, y: 50% };}` but without result.

Answer (score 3):

React draggable has an option named `positionOffSet` which gives us a chance to set the initial offset of the draggable element. This is different than the `defaultPosition` and accepts `%value`. You can check the React Draggable docs for details.

```
<Draggable positionOffset={{ x: '-50%', y: '-50%' }}}>
  <div className='myElement'>
    This is my draggable element
  </div>
</Draggable/>
```

Now, all we need to do is to add few styles to our element like so:

```
.myElement{z-index:999; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;}
```

This will center the modal element in the middle of the page, no matter what dimensions it has.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution but I don't have access no more. 
The solution is to change dynamically position for defaultPosition:
get position of element that has been clicked and dynamically calculate center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CSS transform because `defaultPosition` replace it.

You can use `margin`, I normally use this solution:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

function MyComponent() {

    const [boxSize, setBoxSize] = useState({ w: 0, h: 0 });

    useEffect(() => {

        setBoxSize({
            w: document.querySelector('.container').clientWidth / -2,
            h: document.querySelector('.container').clientHeight / -2
        });

    }, []);

    return (

        <Draggable>
            <div style={{
                marginLeft: boxSize.w,
                marginTop: boxSize.h
            }} className="container">

                {/* ... */}

            </div>
        </Draggable>

    );

}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score -1):

with css3, the best and simple solution for react:

> `.center {
>     margin: 0;
>     position: absolute;
>     top: 50%;
>     left: 50%;
>     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
>   }`

Comment: unfortunately this solution can't work because `defaultPosition` replaces CSS transform

Answer (score -2):

Try to use quotation around your percentages, like `defaultPosition={{ x:  '50%', y: '50%' }}`